# Issue with UITableView. After first touch, scrolls off screen, back to top, using Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm having a problem with UITableView, populated via Core Data. The table view is within a nav controller in a tab bar controller.

It loads correctly, with the right data in the right rows. The problem is, if I touch the table (select a row, enter editing mode, etc) the table quickly scrolls down (animated) and then reappears at the top position (without animation).

This only happens on the first selection after the tableView is displayed for the first time. If I select another tab and come back, there's no issue.

Thank for your help in advance!

UPDATE

This occurs in the Simulator and Device (iPhone 4)

Here's some code

```
    - (void)configureCell:(SavedCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Citation *citation = (Citation *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.citation = citation;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *RecipeCellIdentifier = @"CitationCellIdentifier";

    SavedCell *savedCell = (SavedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RecipeCellIdentifier];
    if (savedCell == nil) {
        savedCell = [[[SavedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:RecipeCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        savedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    [self configureCell:savedCell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return savedCell;
}

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code please for that class

Comment: Which methods would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. In the nib, I had paging enabled. Disabling this seems to solve the issue. There was also a weird scrolling issue separate from the issue above.